# Isn't C++ operator== supposed to be left associative?

Tags: c++

Why does this C++ code print what it prints?

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>

int p(const char *x) {
   printf("%s\n", x);
   return 0;
}

int main()
{
   if (p("LEFT") == p("RIGHT")) ;

   std::vector<int> v1;
   v1.push_back(1);
   std::vector<int>::iterator it = v1.erase(v1.begin());

   if (it == v1.end())
      printf("OK\n");
   else
      printf("FAIL\n");

   std::vector<int> v2;
   v2.push_back(1);
   if (v2.erase(v2.begin()) == v2.end())
      printf("OK\n");
   else
      printf("FAIL\n");

   return 0;
}
```

I'm confused about the OK/FAIL part. This is in contradiction with the LEFT/RIGHT part. What's happening here?

The output for me is:

```
LEFT
RIGHT
OK
FAIL
```

Comment: i think what is more interesting than evaluation order is the fact that a=v2.end();v2.push_back(1);b=v2.end(); and a!=b.  seems a little counter intuitive to me that the (past-end) end() iterator should change after inserting or deleting an element...  this is, in fact, a property of vector.  change it to list and you get something else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Associativity has nothing to do with order of evaluation.

In fact, you're invoking unspecified behavior. You can't tell which part of `==` will evaluate first.

Think about this:

```
int x;  // x is 0 initially
int foo()
{
   x++;
   return x;
}
int goo()
{
   return x;
}

int main()
{
   bool b = foo() == goo();
}
```

If `foo` (returns 1) evaluates first, `b` will be `true` (`goo` will return 1).

If `goo` (returns 0) evaluates first, `b` will be `false` (`foo` will return 1).

Comment: I don't see the UB on `v2`. Remember that function calls introduce sequence points, and all read and modifications on `v2` are done through function calls. _Unspecified_ Behavior, yes.

Comment: No, that would require (A) documentation and (B) consistency. This is a pair of _indeterminably-sequenced_ evaluations. They may be sequenced differently on each execution, but they're always sequenced.

Answer (score 3):

It being left associative does not affect the order in which its parameters are evaluated which is unspecifed by the language. It simply means that if you write "a == b == c" then it will interpret it as ((a==b) == c). But it can calculate a, b and c in advance and in any order it likes.